# Delete column from nested JSON python and the UNION

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have around 30 JSON files with nested attributes, sample shown below. I would like to drop "questionnaire" column from the file and then would like to Union all files.

Could you please suggest how shall we achieve this using Python.

Sample file:

```
 |-- profileEntity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- consent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- documents: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- documentProperties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- documentType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- files: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- edmFileIndex: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- edmFilename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- questionnaire: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- deposit3rdParties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- deposit3rdPartiesOther: string (nullable = true)
```

The reason for this is because "questionnaire" column is not in sync in each file and hence UNION is failing.

Error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.union.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types.

Comment: that example.. does not look like its JSON.. are you sure you are dealing with JSON files?

Comment: You need to post the code that's getting the error, with the full traceback.

Comment: Using below code: file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        file_content1 = file_content.replace("""{"tokenId""", """,{"tokenId""")
        json_string = "[{}]".format(file_content1[1:])
        df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([json_string]))
        print(df.count())
        
        # Verifying if a union for multiple files is necessary or not
        if icount > 0:
            df_raw = df_raw.union(df)
        else:
            df_raw = df
        icount +=1

Comment: Don't put your code in a comment. Edit your question to include your code.